# Error passing a string with Jquery POST

Tags: jquery, post

I'm passing a serialized variable with jquery post method, but I'm getting an error with a specific value:

[image: Error]

This is the value that have been sent throught the POST method:

```
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][id]:300002847
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][code]:22049004
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][code2]:71701
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][name]:CEBOLLA PELADA X KG-20% DE MERMA
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][ptype_id]:300000610
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][formula_quantity]:0.0830612244897959
data[Semiterminados][2][Product][total_quantity]:7.4755102040816315
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][id]:300003899
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][code]:22041041
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][code2]:71708
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][name]:ZANAHORIA LIMPIA X KG MERMA(12.9%)
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][ptype_id]:300000610
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][formula_quantity]:0.03551020408163265
data[Semiterminados][1][Product][total_quantity]:3.1959183673469385
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][id]:300008168
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][code]:22041008
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][code2]:
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][name]:EN CEBOLLADO X KILO
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][ptype_id]:205
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][formula_quantity]:0.5714285714285714
data[Semiterminados][0][Product][total_quantity]:51.42857142857142
data[Materia][6][Product][id]:1693
data[Materia][6][Product][code]:31042004
data[Materia][6][Product][code2]:33202
data[Materia][6][Product][name]:AJO X KL
data[Materia][6][Product][ptype_id]:158
data[Materia][6][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][6][Product][formula_quantity]:0.03061224489795918
data[Materia][6][Product][total_quantity]:2.7551020408163263
data[Materia][9][Product][id]:1783
data[Materia][9][Product][code]:31042064
data[Materia][9][Product][code2]:33237
data[Materia][9][Product][name]:APIO X KILO
data[Materia][9][Product][ptype_id]:158
data[Materia][9][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][9][Product][formula_quantity]:0.026530612244897958
data[Materia][9][Product][total_quantity]:2.387755102040816
data[Materia][8][Product][id]:1834
data[Materia][8][Product][code]:31042025
data[Materia][8][Product][code2]:33210
data[Materia][8][Product][name]:LAUREL X KL
data[Materia][8][Product][ptype_id]:158
data[Materia][8][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][8][Product][formula_quantity]:0.0014285714285714286
data[Materia][8][Product][total_quantity]:0.12857142857142856
data[Materia][7][Product][id]:1809
data[Materia][7][Product][code]:31042018
data[Materia][7][Product][code2]:MP0628
data[Materia][7][Product][name]:CEBOLLITA EN HOJA X KL
data[Materia][7][Product][ptype_id]:158
data[Materia][7][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][7][Product][formula_quantity]:0.16326530612244897
data[Materia][7][Product][total_quantity]:14.693877551020407
data[Materia][2][Product][id]:1798
data[Materia][2][Product][code]:31035009
data[Materia][2][Product][code2]:31563
data[Materia][2][Product][name]:31563.CALDO DE GALLINA O CARNE X KGS
data[Materia][2][Product][ptype_id]:152
data[Materia][2][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][2][Product][formula_quantity]:0.0005183673469387755
data[Materia][2][Product][total_quantity]:0.0466530612244898
data[Materia][5][Product][id]:2788
data[Materia][5][Product][code]:31035048
data[Materia][5][Product][code2]:31502
data[Materia][5][Product][name]:SAL GRUESA X KG
data[Materia][5][Product][ptype_id]:152
data[Materia][5][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][5][Product][formula_quantity]:0.016326530612244896
data[Materia][5][Product][total_quantity]:1.4693877551020407
data[Materia][4][Product][id]:1752
data[Materia][4][Product][code]:31035047
data[Materia][4][Product][code2]:31501
data[Materia][4][Product][name]:SAL FINA X KL
data[Materia][4][Product][ptype_id]:152
data[Materia][4][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][4][Product][formula_quantity]:0.06530612244897958
data[Materia][4][Product][total_quantity]:5.877551020408163
data[Materia][3][Product][id]:1873
data[Materia][3][Product][code]:31035040
data[Materia][3][Product][code2]:31503
data[Materia][3][Product][name]:PIMIENTA  NEGRA EN GRANO X KL
data[Materia][3][Product][ptype_id]:152
data[Materia][3][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][3][Product][formula_quantity]:0.0065306122448979586
data[Materia][3][Product][total_quantity]:0.5877551020408163
data[Materia][1][Product][id]:1775
data[Materia][1][Product][code]:31031005
data[Materia][1][Product][code2]:31101
data[Materia][1][Product][name]:ACEITE  A GRANEL X LT
data[Materia][1][Product][ptype_id]:148
data[Materia][1][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][1][Product][formula_quantity]:0.02040816326530612
data[Materia][1][Product][total_quantity]:1.8367346938775508
data[Materia][0][Product][id]:300000563
data[Materia][0][Product][code]:31011029
data[Materia][0][Product][code2]:32146
data[Materia][0][Product][name]:SAMBARI X KILO
data[Materia][0][Product][ptype_id]:138
data[Materia][0][Product][requested_quantity]:90
data[Materia][0][Product][formula_quantity]:0.8163265306122448
data[Materia][0][Product][total_quantity]:73.46938775510203
data[Materia][preparation]:condimento y cocción de la carne:
- 500 gr de cebolla
- 50 gramos de ajo
- 200 gramos de zanahoria
- 80 gramos sal grusa
- 1 apio
- 2 mazos de laurel
- 1 mazo cebollita
```

If I remove the last value, it work's

```
data[Materia][preparation]:condimento y coccion de la carne
 500 gr de cebolla
 50 gramos de ajo
 200 gramos de zanahoria
 80 gramos sal grusa
 1 apio
 2 mazos de laurel
 1 mazo cebollita
```

**EDIT!!!** I've removed all the special characters but it does not work either!!

Something its wrong with this value. What Can I do??

Please help!.

Comment: That appears to be the only entry with an accent in it. I don't know a lot about character encoding, but that might be a good place to start your investigation.

Comment: That's not the problem. I removed the accent and it still throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is data[Materia] an array? All the other entries are data[Materia][0] or [1] or [2] etc. The last value is just data[Materia][preparation] with no index.

Comment: That's wierd because in my localhost enviroment it works just like that but in production on centOS 7 does not work